# Как обновить массив с state?(Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть начальное состояние, в котором 2 массива,например arr1 и arr2. Первый пустой и заполняется на основе второго (второй не меняется) в процессе работы с модальным окном(там форма). Массивы имеют структуру arr1 = [{},{},{},{}](включают в себя 4 объекта).

Далее хочу реализовать случай, когда пользователь нажимает в модальном окне кнопку cancel и все внесенные им изменения сбрасываются (по коду нужно либо очистить arr1 либо заполнить его объектами из arr2). На кнопку cancel я повесил обработчик:

```
 wizardCancel: function() {
            this.state.arr1 = this.state.arr2;
            console.log( this.state.arr1);
            this.setState({arr1:this.state.arr1});
            this.customizeClose();
        },
```

Консоль лог показывает, что arr1 обновился, но setState его не установил. В чем моя ошибка? И как правильно обновлять массивы\объекты в таких случаях?

Comment: @Утка Учится Уму вычленил дополнительные компоненты и смог сделатьс  помощью хендлера все. спасибо за советы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучьше бы создать метод который будет отдавать состояния по умолчанию и какие-то переменные которые не нужно хранить в состояниях "__getDeaults" в примере, изменять состояния при помощи смешивания текущих состояний и новых (можно сделать это и в "componentWillUpdate" но имхо не практично) "setStateMixin". Для сброса состояний достаточно просто установить состояния по умолчанию 
`this.setState(this.__getDeaults().states);`
[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz5utdpj/5/)

Comment: интересная мысль. по коду есть вопросы. в методе __getDefaults два нижних подчеркивания перед названием. что они значат?еще вопрос насчет setMixins.я не нашел в документации такого метода. это метод,написанный вами,или он где-то есть?в документации упоминаются какие-то mixins и их исопльзование не рекомендуется

Comment: Два подчеркивания ничего не означают, я просто сделал их чтобы выделить этот метод, "setStateMixin" - это мой метод, он же есть в примере кода стр.11. В доке то совсем другое

Comment: все,разобрался. благодаря вашей рекомендации и совету Утка Учится Уму переделал все и заработало. для сброса значений воспользовался отдельным методом по аналогии с вашим.Спасибо

Comment: @Iga, _обычно_ два подчеркивания - значат приватный (по соглашению) метод

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму я видел еще методы, перед которым было одно подчеркивание. они тоже приватные?

Comment: @Iga, они считаются protected. Но нужно понимать что это наследие поборников java-like-oop решивших писать на js, по факту мало кто так делает.